# Build Failed: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior'

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, material-components-android

I'm using  `Android Studio 2.3.3`[image]

I did all the steps below but nothing worked.

```
1) Sync Project with gradle files
2) Build -> Clean Project
3) Build -> Rebuild Project
4) File -> Invalidate caches
```

Comment: Add XML file for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a legacy project trying to configure a material component, would you mind trying these?, though I'm not quite sure if they would help or the version would be compatible, but afaik the `layout_behavior` is part of the design framework.

If its not androidx, try this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'// latest
```

if its androidx, try this then

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-alpha02' //latest
```

These are the latest versions from maven artifacts [com.android.support:design](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/design)
and [com.google.android.material:material](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material)